# Regex to find instances of a string pattern that is not preceded by a carriage return/line feed

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm working in Notepad++

In the file that I'm working with there is a string pattern of `[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|` that every line should start with, immediately followed by a pipe. (A caveat there: the pattern can have up to three capital letters following the four digits. E.g. 00-1324A| or 12-3456STR|).

There are instances in the file where that pattern is in the middle of a line, and needs to be moved to the next line.

Example:

```
00-1234REV|The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog|Test
11-6544|FooBar|text99-8656ST|This needs to be on the next line|some text
45-8737|Peter pipe picked a peck of pickled peppers|TEST2
```

As I noted within the example, `99-8656ST` needs to be moved to the next line, resulting in this:

```js
00-1234REV|The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog|Test
11-6544|FooBar|text
99-8656ST|This needs to be on the next line|some text
45-8737|Peter pipe picked a peck of pickled peppers|TEST2
```

I currently have this regex: `(?<=[^\d\r\n])\d{2}-\d{4}(?!\d)` but that is matching on parts of social security numbers in the middle of a line:

```js
123-45-6789
```

My regex will on `45-6789`.

Comment: Use numeric boundaries then `(?<=[^\d\r\n])(?<!\r\n)\d{2}-\d{4}(?!\d)`, see https://regex101.com/r/G3JocW/2

Comment: You can use this regex: `(?<!^|\d)[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](?!\d)` remembering to activate the multiline mode on the Notepad++ find&replace tool.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that's skipping the phone numbers, but still matches on SSNs

Comment: @horcrux, Notepad++ is complaining that's an invalid regular expression

Comment: Please update the question to see where the numeric boundaries fail. Actually, in my regex, `(?<!\r\n)` became redundant and can be removed. `(?<=[^\d\r\n])\d{2}-\d{4}(?!\d)` will work.

Comment: I mean, `(?<=[^\d\r\n])\d{2}-\d{4}(?!\d)` does what you need. If not, show what is wrong in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I updated the question to include your regex, which still matches on SSNs, as indicated in the updated question. Also, I added a critical piece of information about the pattern to search for: it always is followed by a pipe.

Comment: Include hyphens into boundaries, `(?<=[^\d\r\n-])\d{2}-\d{4}(?!-?\d)`

Comment: Ok, so, it seems you need `(?<=[^\r\n\d-])\d{2}-\d{4}(?=[A-Z]{0,3}\|)`. Or `(?<=[^\d\r\n])(?<!\d-)\d{2}-\d{4}(?=[A-Z]{0,3}\|)`. The left-hand boundary condition is not that clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since purely numeric boundaries do not work here, you can add up a check for a digit + hyphen on the left. The right-hand boundary is clear, it is zero to three uppercase letters followed with a pipe.

That means, you can use

```js
(?<=[^\d\r\n])(?<!\d-)\d{2}-\d{4}(?=[A-Z]{0,3}\|)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LYoWeq/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=[^\d\r\n])` - immediately on the left, there must be a char other than a digit, CR, LF
- `(?<!\d-)` - immediately on the left, there should be no digit + `-`
- `\d{2}-\d{4}` - two digits, `-`, four digits
- `(?=[A-Z]{0,3}\|)` - immediately followed with 0 to 3 uppercase letters and then a literal `|` char.

If the left-hand boundary can be a single hyphen or digit, then replace `(?<=[^\d\r\n])(?<!\d-)` with `(?<=[^\r\n\d-])`.